# problem casting a void* to a (vector<void*>*)

Tags: c++, vector, casting, callback, void-pointers

I am currently working on a complex logic, where I have a `map<string,void*>` with these value:

```
string mystring[10] = {"key1","key2","keyN"};
for(string s: mystrings){
    vector<void*> v;
    v.push_back(this);
    v.push_back(&s);
    map.insert({s,&v});
}
```

At a certain point, I have to pass my `vector` to a timer which triggers a callback:

```
mytimer(int milliseconds, mycallback,void* (parameter of the callback));
this->mytimer(1000,MY_CALLBACK,map.at("Key1"));
```

The problem is in the callback:

```
static void MY_CALLBACK(void*);
void MY_CALLBACK(void* args){
    auto obj = (vector<void*>*) args;
    auto key = (string*) obj->at(1);
    auto logic = (MY_CLASS *) obj->at(0);
    some logic;
}
```

The program crashes because of an "out of range" error when I try to get any value of the `vector`.

What is the problem?

Comment: `v.push_back(&s);` -- You are adding a pointer to a temporary variable.  What do you think will happen to that variable every time the loop iterates?

Comment: there is no need to use `void*` in modern c++ for type erasure. Consider to use `std::variant` or  `std::any`

Comment: `map.insert({s,&v});` adds the address of a local variable `v` (to the map) which then goes out of scope, leaving a dangling pointer.

Comment: Remember to delete the `s` key from the map before getting to the end of each for-loop, or it will have a dangling `void*` to a destructed local temporary.  That could cause problems.

Comment: The first code snippet is totally wrong -- there is no need to go further into looking at the other code you posted.

Comment: `vector<void*>` -- Instead of this, why not use `vector<std::pair<MY_CLASS*, string>>`?  Then in the callback, you're not finagling around with `void *` to determine the `key` and `logic`, since they will be both stored in the `std::pair`.

Comment: This style of coding, with lots of pointers and casting, is a very dated way of doing things that people don't do anymore because it's notoriously difficult to get right--and for a beginner to even begin to understand.  The advice to use std::any or variant can't be overstated.  If you are stuck in some legacy hell where std::any isn't available then use boost, or it's actually very easy to implement if you read the documentation of boost's version.  Only reason to do it this way is if you are told to--and then I'd be looking for work elsewhere because unnecessary frustration sucks.

Comment: _Guessing_ when programming in C++ usually brings a lot of grief. It's not a very forgiving language.

Comment: This is [XY problem](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem). This code is broken beyond repair. If you explain what it should do/why you need this, you will get proper solution. For example where this `MY_CALLBACK` come from?

Comment: `static void MY_CALLBACK(void*);` -- If this is a legacy `C` callback you are trying to interface, then *maybe* the `void *` right there would be understandable.  But the issue with your code is that you've made almost everything `void*` when it doesn't have to be.  There is absolutely no reason, given your code, to have `vector<void *>` being used.  The only `void *`, should be that parameter to `MY_CALLBACK`, nothing else.  If you find yourself `void *`-ing up the rest of the code, then it is a huge code smell.

Comment: Try to program with fewer pointers. Not very helpful right now, but good advice in the long run. And I agree with all the comments above, this code is broken beyond repair. If you didn't know what a dangling pointer is, then you've learned the hard way. If you did then you weren't paying attention, which is another good lesson.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here

> ```
> for(string s: mystrings){
>      vector<void*> v;
>      v.push_back(this);
>      v.push_back(&s);
>      map.insert({s,&v});
>    }
> ```

You are inserting a pointer to a vector whose lifetime ends at the end of the iteration. The pointer in the map is useless. Its a dangling pointer. Later dereferencing the pointer leads to undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

You are storing pointers to objects that are destroyed before you have a chance to use the pointers.

Your `for` loop is iterating the `string[]` array, pushing a pointer to a *copy* of each `string` into the `vector`. The *copy* is destroyed at the end of the current iteration.  And, the `vector` itself is local to each iteration, so it is also destroyed after you have pushed a pointer to it into the `map`.

For what you are attempting, try something more like this:

```
using var = std::variant<MY_CLASS*, std::string>;
using vec = std::vector<var>;

...

std::map<std::string, vec> my_map;

...

std::string mystring[10] = {"key1", "key2", "keyN"};
for(auto& s: mystrings){
    vec v;
    v.emplace_back(this);
    v.emplace_back(s);
    my_map.insert({s, std::move(v)});
}

...

this->mytimer(1000, MY_CALLBACK, &(my_map.at("key1")));

...

void MY_CALLBACK(void* args){
    auto v = static_cast<vec*>(args);
    auto logic = std::get<MY_CLASS*>(v->at(0));
    auto key = std::get<std::string>(v->at(1));
    // use logic and key as needed...
}
```

Note, this assumes you are not modifying the contents of the `map` while the timer is running.  If you do, then you will need to create the `vector` dynamically instead, eg:

```
using var = std::variant<MY_CLASS*, std::string>;
using vec = std::vector<var>;

...

std::map<std::string, std::unique_ptr<vec>> my_map;

...

std::string mystring[10] = {"key1", "key2", "keyN"};
for(auto& s: mystrings){
    auto v = std::make_unique<vec>();
    v->emplace_back(this);
    v->emplace_back(s);
    my_map.insert({s, std::move(v)});
}

...

this->mytimer(1000, MY_CALLBACK, my_map.at("key1").get());

...

void MY_CALLBACK(void* args){
    auto v = static_cast<vec*>(args);
    auto logic = std::get<MY_CLASS*>(v->at(0));
    auto key = std::get<std::string>(v->at(1));
    // use logic and key as needed...
}
```